# ajax request & response encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption

I want to encrypt the request & response sent from my pages, what is the easiest and  most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on what threats you want to protect your data from. If it's only eavesdropping, HTTPS would be enough. If you ned to secure cookies or your use of HTML 5 local storage, then you should think about encryption and the mechanisms are different then.

Answer (score 3):

use https for secure sending of data

Answer (score 1):

[Transport Layer Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/transport_layer_security) (TLS).  This is the successor to SSL, and all major web servers support it.